# Is it possible to pivot table without specifying column and row names in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Is it possible to pivot dataframe table without specifying column and row names in Pandas?

Input is:

```
    a  b  c
0   .  .  .
1   .  .  .
2   .  .  .
```

Output should be:

```
    0  1  2
a   .  .  .
b   .  .  .
c   .  .  .
```

Comment: Do you just want to transpose it? `df.T`?

Comment: Yes, I have not used T before. That is awesome and simple and awesome and simple!

Comment: You might want to read some of the numpy docs before diving into pandas. Not necessary per se, but extremely helpful.